# ROS Answers SE migration: import _Twist

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the code on the book and the tutorials are something like this:`from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist`,but when I type `from geometry_msgs.msg import T`,the sublime auto-completes it to this:`from geometry_msgs.msg import _Twist`.An underscore appears.Is it OK?And I find there is only `_Twist.py` in `/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geometry_msgs/msg`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260753/import-_twist/) by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2017-05-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) on 2017-05-02**:
Just `Twist` should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know.`import`here imports the class `Twist`,and this class exists in the module`_Twist.py`

---

Originally posted by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) with karma: 88 on 2017-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0